# javascript debugging - is there a way to tell what functions are being executed?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm examining someone else's code and I'm trying to find out what functions are executing when I take certain actions. Is there a way in firebug to do this? (or any other way).

In this particular case I'm trying to find out what happens when I click the 'next' and 'previous' buttons in the editor found at http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, "Live Data Manipulation >> Navigator" (then clicking the pencil, then the arrows at the bottom).

I've tried grabbing the item I'm clicking and looking at its properties in the console by doing this:

```
>>> obj = $('#nData')
>>> console.log(obj)
```

but there doesn't seem to be a handler for click.

What would be wonderful if if there's a way to see what functions are called when I perform an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) may be of some use to you. It hooks into Firebug and displays additional meta-data on all DOM elements which have been modified by JQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I agree FireQuery is really handy for this

Comment: This ended up getting me the function, but not solving the problem I needed the function for. Ah, well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebug's "Break on next" (the pause looking button in the toolbar)

Then you can the step buttons to move around. Set it to use that, and then click whichever button you want to check the action for.

Since my description probably sucks, check [this](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-15-break-on-next/) out.

Edit: This sounds like what you want:

> It's primary goal is breaking the Javascript execution at required place in the code that is unknown to the developer beforehand. The typical example, probably well known to most web developers is: "Where in the hell is the code, which is executed if I click this button?".

Comment: This is helpful but not quite doing it. Its just showing me the jQuery selector code, I can't quite use it to get to the onclick event. +1 for a nice new trick for me!

Comment: You can do F10 after "break on next" until you hit the code that you can recognize. Also use stack as well, it might show you were the call came from.  
One additional way to do this would be to turn on Firebug profiler and hit the button, then turn it off, and it will show you the list of all functions executed, from there you should be able to pin-point correct function.

Answer (score 0):

In firebug, in the Script tab, put a breakpoint in the line you want to inspect. In the right, there is a "Stack" tab where you can see the current stack trace!

Comment: If I knew where to put the breakpoint, I'd already know what code was executing.